# Javascript hash into Rails create method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails app and I've got survey where I collect data with jQuery.

I serialize answers into something like:

```
{question-1: "4", question-2: "3", question-4: "4"}
```

Which I then convert into:

```
[{question_id: 1, response: "4"}, {question_id:2, response: "3"}, {question_id:4, response: "4"}]
```

Now I've got Answer model with question_id and response fields.
What's the best way to get the js answer hashes into Answer.create method to create three answer records in the above example?

I've done something like that before but only creating one record at the time, submitting the form for user with js hash like

```
{name: "T", email: "test@example.com", phone: "01234568"}
```

but I can't seem to get my head around dealing with multiple hashes.

Comment: Can you not just loop over the array passing each hash into `Answer.create`?

Comment: Possibly. But since I'm sending form through javascript code, that would mean looping over the array in the javascript and getting sendForm function there about 80 times. Not ideal and I was wondering whether I could deal with that on the rails side